# Data Layers lining up!

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am having issues with a data layer that is not lining up with my other data layers!  What do I do?

I have all the parcel polygons, parcel pts. Jurisdiction polygons from Ashtabula county that all line up (I received these data layers all from the same source...from Ashtabula county).  Then I bring in a data layer for street centerlines from OGRIP (where I have obtained all my other street centerline data from that works great!)

How do I get these to work?  The extents on the street centerline data are completely different from the other data layers.

The projected coordinate systems are the same in all the layers?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, edit your question with the "bad" extent and someone may be able to tell you what coordinate system it's supposed to have. (and hi, fellow buckeye!)

Comment: Where did you get your other county data from? I received shapefiles from Ashtabula a few years back and included in the data was a centerline shapefile projected correctly.  The LBRS is in meters, which is screwing it up because the False Easting doesn't line up.

Comment: Please edit this question instead of creating a new one. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186740/data-layers-not-lining-up

Comment: Your other question has the coordinate reference system, but not the extent of the centerline data. Please edit the question and include that information.